# How can surface deform only use part of the mesh?

Tags: surface-deform

I have made some nails on fingers. Now the fingers are parented to the bones and are animated. The nails I also parented to the top finger bone, so the nails also move. But the bottom of the nail moves upwards from the 'skin'. So I tried surface deform. But with that the top of the nail also deforms with the skin, which it shouldn't.

So, how can I apply the surface deform only for some part of the mesh (eq the bottom of the nails)?

The nails are just 2D mesh with Solidify
[image]

file:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The nail is rigid: it doesn't need to deform. Could you consider just vertex-parenting the nail to the skin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a Vertex Group to include or exclude from the SurfaceDeform modifier.

So I took the 'nail ring.001' object, chose a group of vertices in Edit Mode, and created a new Vertex Group that I renamed "nail base":

[image]

All of these vertices got a default weight of 1.000.  I could have gotten fancier to Weight Paint around the transition, perhaps if needed for perfection.

I then used this in the Vertex Group property of the SurfaceDeform modifier.   Where before it was blank (implying all vertices of the *nail* would be deformed):

[image]

Now instead only the vertices specified would be modified:

[image]

Here is a copy of your modified file: [image]

As a fan of the USA series "Saturday Night Live" (comedy), I saw the name of your file and though of the "Church Lady" skit where she yells *SATAN!*.